# Java logging annotations

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, lombok

I am looking for an annotation library that will help me in debugging e.g. production performance issues.

The other day I was seeing timeout error logs from service A, who was calling service B. That is service B was taking too long to respond even though it did the job eventually.

What I ended up doing was sprinkling all the involved methods in service B with log statements so that I could see where we got stuck, and redeployed the service.

It would have nice if there was an annotation on method level, or preferably on class level that I could apply on the relevant classes, that in it's simpledst form would log e.g. "method entererd" and "method exited".

I am using sl4j, and logback.

Comment: Seems like a trivial AOP task, no? In any case, requests for libraries are OT on SO.

Comment: Look at [jcab-aspects](https://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html) and [controller-logger](https://github.com/controller-logger/controller-logger). If you need customization, these libraries will give you an idea at least.

Comment: yes, as others says this is an AOP task. you can check this https://medium.com/@wkrzywiec/moving-into-next-level-in-user-log-events-with-spring-aop-3b4435892f16 It helped me to achieve something similar.